# std::out_of_range error

Tags: c++, opencv, std, out

I am working on the following code in opencv in Linux Ubuntu.
x_captured and y_captured are "int" type vectors.  Size of both vectors is 18.

```
for (int i=0;i<=x_captured.size();i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<=y_captured.size();j++)
    {
        if (i!=j)
        {
            if (((x_captured.at(j)-x_captured.at(i))<=2) && 
                ((y_captured.at(j)-y_captured.at(i))<=2))
            {
                consecutive=consecutive+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i=0 and j=18 after that it throws the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  vector::_M_range_check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<=x_captured.size();i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<=y_captured.size();j++)
```

You should change the `<=` to `<` and try again.

[image]

Example array named Billy : Size : 5 but last index is 4. Get it? :)

Comment: Please credit your sources: ["Complete C++ Tutorial"](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) (click for more!) by Juan Soulié (download [as PDF](http://www.cplusplus.com/files/tutorial.pdf))

Comment: @sehe Haha well that was the first place to search that came to mind :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using looping from 0 to N when valid indices are 0 to N - 1. This is why you are getting an exception on the last iteration: `std::vector::at` performs bound checking, if you are out of bounds then an `std::out_of_range` is thrown.

You need to change your loop's condition to `<`, not `<=`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x_captured.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < y_captured.size(); j++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```